# Torsion-free sheaf on etale site

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

If $F$ is a sheaf on usual Zariski site of an integral scheme $X$ (each $O_U(U)$ is a domain), then it is called torsion-free if $F(U)$ is torsion-free $O_U(U)$ module for every $U\in X_{Zar}$.

Now how to define a torsion-free sheaf on the small etale site of a integral scheme? The problem is unlike the Zariski case, $O_U(U)$ are not integral domains ( reduced but not irreducible/connected) when $U \in X_{et}$. Moreover, this also shows that even the structure sheaf for $X_{et}$ is not torsion-free.

So my first guess was to define $F$ in $X_{et}$ as torsion-free if $F|_{X_{zar}}$ is torsion-free. However, it seems to me that I am making some mistake.

Comment: It just means a torsion free abelian group for all $U$.

Comment: We are looking for torsion free as $\mathcal O_U(U)$-modules. More generally, we would like to do this by setting the torsion submodule to $0$. If $M$ is an $A$-module, its torsion submodule is not defined unless $A$ is an integral domain. However, if $U=Spec(A)\longrightarrow X$ is an etale morphism, then $A$ is not necessarily an integral domain (it may be shown that $A$ is reduced).

Comment: @sam: *torsion free* makes sense for reduced rings $A$: a torsion element is one which is annihilated by some non-zero divisor in $A$.  More geometrically, a f.g. module is torsion free if the support of the corresponding coherent sheaf is a union of irred. comps. of Spec $A$.

Comment: @tracing: Isn't some condition like $A$ Noetherian (or that the irreducible components of Spec $A$ are locally finite) required? Could you help me with a reference to read about this torsion free modules for reduced rings ?

Comment: @sam: I think the definition makes sense generally (even for non-reduced rings), but you are right that for the theory of associated primes to behave well under localization one needs something like a Noetherian hypothesis.  (In the non-Noetherian context, the formation of associated primes need not commute with localization.)    I've not thought about things like the stack of torsion free sheaves in a non-Noetherian context (since people usually consider such things for varieties and other highly Noetherian situations); does the Stacks project say anything?

Comment: But also, if the base is integral, then any etale cover will be locally integral, right?  This should make things easier to handle.

Comment: @tracing: Being integral is not an etale local property but being reduced is. The problem is with irreducibility ( or even connectedness). I couldn't find about torsion free sheaf for etale site in Stack Project. However, I just found yesterday that EGA (1970) has a discussion about torsion free sheaf on reduced schemes. And you are correct to say that torsion free makes sense for any general ring too, but I am not sure if that definition actually gives a torsion theory!

Comment: @Sam: Yes, I got confused.    What I meant to say was something along the lines of: the irreducible component structure of the complete local ring at a point is an etale local invariant --- but this presumes that completions are reasonably behaved, so gets us back to the Noetherian context.  I have to confess that I don't know much about how torsion phenomena behave in the non-Noetherian setting.    Do you specifically have to consider non-Noetherian contexts?

Comment: @tracing: Not really..but I would like to know if there is a definition in general. However, EGA also assumes finitely many irreducible components ( in particular Noetherian) while defining torsion free. So, I don't know if one can define it in more generality.